File deleted during pull
I pushed to gitlab with my changes I deleted a file and then my friend pulled the changes so the same file was deleted and the coding was also deleted on my friend's device, so how do I get my friend's file back?
I have done restore file via commit but it only restore file that I have deleted not my friend file

With respect to the above question, if you've only just deleted the file in the last commit, then using git checkout HEAD^ -- path/to/file should also work. This incident also demonstrates the importance of working on feature branches and pull/merge requests plus code review.

I think you can't restore your friends file if he pull the last changes without stash his current changes.
Tell your friend to try:
git stash

To recover his file changes. It's the only thing I can think of to do.

Okey i will try
